# Distinct count in pivot adds 'empty' to pivot

Tags: count, pivot-table, distinct, distinct-values, excel-2019

I was happy to find out there is an option for a distinct count in pivottables.
I used it, but found out something happened which I cannot explain:

When I use the normal `count` command, I get a nice, decent table containing all the values in the (in this case) column. I checked the cells, I have filled all the empty cells with a value:

[image: count image]

but when I switch to `unique count`, suddenly the table has an 'empty' between the values. But only 1:

[image: uniqe count table]

I checked the data, there is no empty between the values. When I select the column, use 'go to' > 'special' > 'empty cells' I get this message:
[image: no cells found]

'No cells found'.

Why does this happen when using the unique count option?

I check the end of the data range (select the last filled row: ctrl + arrow down) in my file:
[image: end data table]

this is the file with the column headers in row 1.

When I compare this to Powerpivot (select the last row, ctrl + arrow down), I see the Powerpivot range ends in row 369692 while this should be 369691 (the column headers are not in row 1 anymore):
[image: enddata powerpivot]

The only thing I can come up with now is that I see powerpivot works with blocks of 4 rows apparently, where the last row in the last block is empty:

[image: powerpivot rows]

When I filter the specific column in Powerpivot on 'Empty', I get this:
[image: powerpivot empty filter]

The row number is strange because row 1 is filled normally:
[image]

But still, how does Powerpivot find an empty row in the data range when there is no empty row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible causes with solutions

- *hidden characters or space*s in the data that are causing the `(blank)` value to appear. using the `TRIM` function will remove them
- Issue with the data source or the connection to the data source. You can try refreshing the data source and see if that resolves the issue.
- `placeholder row` in your data source could be causing the `(blank)` value to appear when using the `Distinct Count function` in a `pivot table.` If there is a `placeholder` row in your data source that contains empty cells or cells with *hidden characters or spaces*, it could be counted as a `unique value` by the `Distinct` Count function.

Comment: I still struggle with this. Now in a different situation. Pivot is perfectly made up. Datarange is strictly limited to the data range, not even a range of columns, but a range of specific cells. At first, in the powerpivot data, there was a row which was blank beside 1 data value, " Kwart 0". I removed this line, and refreshed the data but still, the empty is added to the pivot. I cannot understand why this emtpy line is added when without distinctive count everything is working as it should be.

Comment: to add to my last comment: When I created a new data model from the powerpivot tab, de 'empty' is gone. I am not sure if deleting range1 helped (i had 2 ranges in powerpivot diagram view)